# Can't access GRUB when dual booting

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, windows-8

Currently dual booting with Win8 and Xubuntu 17.04, in legacy mode. However I cannot get GRUB to prompt unless I load [YUMI](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) first, then get redirected to GRUB. I have tried disabling Hibernation mode and Fa st Startup mode. When looking at the boot order from BIOS, I see an entry for Windows Boot Manager but nothing for Linux. What else can I try?

Comment: Please read https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI first.

Comment: I made a quick video for Windows Boot edit...https://youtu.be/23712F5vC-k

Comment: @mook765 Win8 came as legacy not UEFI, and I have already read that.

Comment: Please boot to Ubuntu, open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and then run the command `sudo fdisk -l`. then copy the output and paste it into your question via [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/912930/edit), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably install your linux distro in the same mode as your windows. Since it's Windows 8, it is probably in UEFI mode. Therefore, it might work when you install linux in UEFI mode as well.

Comment: I checked, and Win8 is not UEFI but legacy.

Answer (score -1):

At first you want to make sure that:
***secure boot** is off
***fast startup** is disabled before installing linux os (no need of disabling hibernation)
*create new patition from windows using "**disk management**"
*You should enter to **"live boot install"**

1. Suppose after doing above method, if you can't access grub then try press <kbd>Esc</kbd> when starting the OS.
2. If <kbd>Esc</kbd> key is not working. Then enter into Linux OS installig. Installing After installing, don't immediately shutdown installing. Open the terminal and enter:    `sudo update-grub`